# How to implement a "master" Id value in a column of a database table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have 3 tables like the following:

**Person**
    PersonId INT  [PK, unique clust idx, identity yes]
    PersonName VARCHAR(50)  [non-null]
    ContactId INT  [unique non-clust idx, non-null, FK to Contact table's ContactId column]

**Company**
    CompanyId INT  [PK, unique clust idx, identity yes]
    CompanyName VARCHAR(100)  [non-null]
    ContactId INT  [unique non-clust idx, non-null, FK to Contact table's ContactId column]

**Contact**
    ContactId INT  [PK, unique clust idx, identity yes]
    CreatedDate DATETIME  [non-null, default value getdate()]

I will show the desired end results during the following 3 insert operations (starting with all empty tables)...

I insert a row into Person, and want to end up with:

**Person table** -
    PersonId     1
    PersonName   'First Person'
    ContactId    1

**Contact table** -
    ContactId    1
    CreatedDate  getdate() value

I then insert a row into Company, and want to end up with:

**Company table** -
    CompanyId    1
    CompanyName  'First Company'
    ContactId    2

**Contact table** -
    ContactId    2
    CreatedDate  getdate() value

I insert a second row into Person, and want to end up with:

**Person table** -
    PersonId     2
    PersonName   'Second Person'
    ContactId    3

**Contact table** -
    ContactId    3
    CreatedDate  getdate() value

I hope the above makes it clear what I am trying to accomplish, i.e., I want to use the Contact table as a sort of "unique value generator" type mechanism, so to speak, so that anytime I insert a row into Person or Company (or any additional tables that I want to put a similar ContactId column into), each ContactId value in any/all of those tables will be unique.

What would be the most efficient way to accomplish this?  Is it possible to do this with triggers on the Person and Company tables so that I can only do one insert operation from my application code (and if so, what would the trigger code look like)?  Or will I always have to do multiple I/O operations from my application code, in which I first insert a row to the Contact table, get the scope_identity() value back, then use that value for the ContactId value on the insert to Person or Company?  Or some other methodology that is better than either one of those?

Any insights are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also, I apologize for the formatting of my post - I tried to use carriage returns but they didn't seem to "take"...

Comment: um... one minor question, how exactly does one make sure carriage returns "work" in one's posts?  I searched the FAQ and didn't see anything about this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have a [sequence](http://documentation.basis.com/BASISHelp/WebHelp/b3odbc/sql_sequences.htm) for your contactId and insert values from the sequence for contactId based on triggers

Comment: Holy cow!  I have been doing SQL Server for 15 years and I have never seen the CREATE SEQUENCE stuff, so thanks for that tip (might be useful for some other things).  However, I'm not sure it helps in my specific situation.  If I understand CREATE SEQUENCE correctly (after checking out your great link)...

Comment: ... if in my scenario the Contact table didn't even exist, and all I needed to do was to have a unique set of values in a particular column across two or more tables, CREATE SEQUENCE would work.  But I do need to have the ContactId value in the Contact table be the "master" value, so to speak (it will actually be used by as the FK target from some other tables).  So in that case, it doesn't seem like CREATE SEQUENCE would be enough (and I would still likely need to do something like the two-inserts-from-my-application-code technique).  Or am I missing something?

Comment: you need to make sure that before inserting into person or company table a trigger inserts the sequence's next value in contact table and then you insert the sequence's current value into the actual table

Comment: Hmmm... but if I use a before-insert trigger, on the Person table for example, couldn't I just do the insert to Contact table (the way I have the Contact table defined), get the scope_identity() value from that insert, and then use that value for the ContactId value for Person, rather than using the CREATE SEQUENCE technique?  Or is there some issue with doing it that way?

Comment: yep.since you are using sql server you can make your id in contact table as identity (which in turn means it is going to be implemented as a sequence internally) and get its value using scope_identity. But the  benefit with having a separate sequence is you can have control over it

Comment: OK - makes sense.  Thanks so much for your help!  Time to go bang out some code now :)

Comment: * Note for anyone else looking at this, technically there is no before insert trigger type in MS SQL Server; but the "INSTEAD OF INSERT" trigger functions almost the same way (everything about the above discussion is the same).

Comment: * Also note that the CREATE SEQUENCE is new with SQL Server 2012!  BTW I came up with a completely different implementation for my scenario - but this was a good exercise to go thru anyway.